# What are the minimal degrees of the real and imaginary part of an algebraic complex number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $z=a+bi\in\mathbb C$ with $b\ne0$ be an algebraic complex number of minimal degree $n$. It is obvious that $a=\dfrac {z+\bar{z}}2$ and $b=\dfrac {z-\bar{z}}{2i}$ are also algebraic. For $n=3$, it is easy to see form Cardano's formula that $a$ is of minimal degree $3$ and that $b$ must be in general of minimal degree $6$. For general $n$, it is also clear from looking at $iz$ that the minimal degree of $b$ is "at worst" the double of the one of $a$. Question:

> For $n\ge4$, which is in the general case the minimal degree of $a$?

(By "general case", I mean excluding special cases like a symmetrical minimal polynomial etc.)

Comment: This is just Galois theory. What is the size of the subgroup of $S_n$ that fixes $z_i+z_j$?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Yes, of course it is. And I'd like to know: what is the "worst case scenario"?

Comment: The worst case scenario is when the Galois group of the minimal polynomial of $z$ is $S_n$, in this case the index in $S_n$ of the subgroup in my first comment is the answer to your question.

Comment: So I suppose in the most general setting, the subgroup of $S_n$ that fixes $z+\bar {z}$ (if that is what you mean) is just $S_2$, is that correct? Thus the answer would be $n!/2$.

Comment: No. $S_2\times S_{n-2}$, the order is $2(n-2)!$ and the index is $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Thank you. Why not write that as an answer?